# Multiple output in single line Shell commend with pipe only

Tags: shell, unix

For example:
`ls -l -d */ | wc -l | awk '{print $1}' | tee /dev/tty | ls -l`

This shell command print the result of wc and ls -l with single line, but tee is used.

Is it possible to using **one** Shell commend line to achieve multiple output **without** using “**&&**” “**||**” “**>**” “**>>**” “**<**” “**;**” “**&**”,**tee** and **temp file**?

Comment: Why are you piping the output of `tee` or `awk` to `ls`?  `ls` doesn't read from standard input at all.   Please clearly state what output you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, This isn't very clear what you're asking. Post any code you have already tried. Also, check this post out to see how to get fast answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want the output of `date` and `ls -rtl | head -1` on one line, you can use

```
echo "$(date): $(ls -rtl | head -1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve writing to multiple files with `awk` which is not in the list of things you appear not to like:

```
echo hi | awk '{print > "a.txt"; print > "b.txt"}'
```

Then check `a.txt` and `b.txt`.